# I'm trying to write a conditional based on what comes back from an AJAX success call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to check the db to make sure a user name doesn't already exist during a registration process.  I have it getting the count from the db.

**PHP Code:**

```
if($result=mysql_query("SELECT count(*) from users where username='$requsername'"))
{
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $usercount=$row[0];        
        echo $usercount;
    }
}
else
{
    $goof=mysql_error();
    $error = "<b>Error:</b>  $goof";
    echo $error;
}
```

**jQuery code:**

```
$('#newusername').blur(function() {
    var requsername=$('#newusername').val(),
    dataString='requsername=' + requsername;
    $.ajax({
        url:'scripts/checkusername.php',
        data:  dataString,
        type:'POST',
        success:  function(data) {
            var response=data;
            if(response==="0") {
                $('#usernamestat').html('Username Available');
                $('#addusrbtn').removeAttr('disabled');
                alert(response);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But it is ignoring the value of data.  I did an alert and it is alerting the number from the db but it isn't running the code to enable my button and say username available.  I do not know what I"m doing wrong! I want it to either pass or fail - if it passes (no users found with that username requested) it enables the submit button and lets them continue; but if it does not pass and has a value of greater than 0, it displays an error message that the username is already taken.  It is not working at all or recognizing the numbers at all!

Comment: Please indent you code properly

Comment: If your alert is working, that if must be returning true. What's the HTML look like?

Comment: Have you checked your console for errors?

Comment: This stupid forum thing isn't letting me paste my HTML in - complains it's too long.

Comment: We don't need to see ALL of the HTML, only the relevant parts: the stuff around #usernamestat and #addusrbtn.

Comment: Agreed with @versalle88 - check $('#usernamestat').length and $('#addusrbtn').length to make sure your jQuery calls are affecting elements.

Also, no need for a while loop in your PHP; since you're only expecting a single row back, just do `$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);`

Comment: isn't your zero an `int` instead of a `string`

Comment: Just saw this, but you're missing a number of end parenthesis ) around the brackets..

Answer (score 1):

Are you even sure whether your ajax call is made? From what i recall you don't supply data to jquery ajax functions in form key=value but in form {key: value}

When you can't guess what you do wrong, do some debugging:

- use `console.log(data)`
- or use developer tools or firebug and put a breakpoint inside you success function.
- Or have a look at network tab and see what your ajax request headers was and what was the response.
- Put `vardump` in php code.
- Use a decent IDE that allows real tume line by line debugging of PHP ...
- install xdebug

So many ways to do it...

I use Php storm debugger 3 hours a day , Dev tools another 3  :)

Answer (score 1):

1)

```
//Hope this might help 
    //check wether control goes to else part
        success:  function(data) {
                    var response=data;
                    if(response==="0") {
                        $('#usernamestat').html('Username Available');
                        $('#addusrbtn').removeAttr('disabled');
                        alert(response);
                    }else{
                       alert("Username not available");
                }



     //if it goes to else part then change your if condition to 
        if(response === 0) {//return from php might be of integer operator(===) needs value along with type to be same
            -----
            -----
        }
        OR
        if(response == "0")
```

Answer (score 0):

use mysql_num_rows instead of
while loop.
it will give you number of rows.
then you check as

```
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result); 
if($num_rows > 0)
{
echo 'usename already exist.';
}
```